# Material-UI InputBase is creating another text-area hidden element

Tags: material-ui, wai-aria

I'm improving my app with Material-UI and the goal is achieve full accessibility. I'm using WAVE chrome extension in order to inspect it.

When I inspect with WAVE, the Material-UI InputBase component, with multiline, to create a text-area, I figured out that is creating a second text-area with `aria-hidden: true` and `visibility: hidden` in styles

[image]

This is my Material-UI InputBase customized component:

```
<InputBase
           id="input-container"
           name="input-container"
           fullWidth
           multiline
           value={content}
           label={textPlaceholder}
           placeholder={textPlaceholder}
           onChange={onChangeContent}
           inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'post' }}
         />
```

and this is how I customized it in theme.js

```
MuiInputBase: {
      root: {},
      multiline: {
        fontFamily: 'Circular Book',
        fontWeight: '300',
        minHeight: 56,
        maxHeight: 400,
        fontSize: 24,
        color: 'black',
        marginTop: 24,
        padding: '0 8px 20px',
        letterSpacing: 'normal'
      }
    },
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. No idea what that hidden textarea element is for or why Material-UI puts it there. It's definitely the 'multiline' prop that's adding it though.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

**2020-12-28**

Material-UI InputBase Component has a conditional that forces to create a textarea element if you don't have rowMin & rowMax props together with multiline prop. If not, instead it will create a TextareaAutoSize Component. But TextareaAutoSize has 2 textarea elements, and the second is the hidden one.

[InputBase link](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.2/packages/material-ui/src/InputBase/InputBase.js)

[TextareaAutoSize link](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.2/packages/material-ui/src/TextareaAutosize/TextareaAutosize.js#L163)

**InputBase:**

```
else if (multiline) {
    if (rows && !rowsMax && !rowsMin) {
      InputComponent = 'textarea';
    } else {
      inputProps = {
        rows,
        rowsMax,
        ...inputProps,
      };

      InputComponent = TextareaAutosize;
    }
}
```

**TextareaAutosize:**

```
 return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <textarea
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        ref={handleRef}
        // Apply the rows prop to get a "correct" first SSR paint
        rows={rowsMin}
        style={{
          height: state.outerHeightStyle,
          // Need a large enough difference to allow scrolling.
          // This prevents infinite rendering loop.
          overflow: state.overflow ? 'hidden' : null,
          ...style,
        }}
        {...other}
      />
      <textarea
        aria-hidden
        className={props.className}
        readOnly
        ref={shadowRef}
        tabIndex={-1}
        style={{ ...styles.shadow, ...style }}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
```

So, in order to avoid hidden elements and ensuring accessibility, you must define rows, without rowMin and rowMax

```
<InputBase
           id="input-container"
           name="input-container"
           fullWidth
           multiline
           value={content}
           rows={3}
           label={textPlaceholder}
           placeholder={textPlaceholder}
           onChange={onChangeContent}
           inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'post' }}
         />
```